# Добавить значения в новый тип атрибутов WP

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Необходимо добавить новый тип атрибута.

Делал следующее:

```
add_filter("product_attributes_type_selector" , function( $array ){
    $array["checkbox"] = __( 'Checkbox', 'woocommerce' );
    return $array ;
});
```

В итоге тип добавлялся, но пропали все его значения

http://joxi.ru/Vm6ZJvKTD5Lb8m

http://joxi.ru/vAWz74Wt1o8q52

Я так понимаю их нужно связать, но как это сделать?. С помощью какого хука?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно использовать хук `woocommerce_product_option_terms`

```
add_filter("product_attributes_type_selector", function ($array) {
    $array["single"] = __('single', 'woocommerce');
    return $array;
});

add_action('woocommerce_product_option_terms', 'product_option_terms', 20, 2);

function product_option_terms($attribute_taxonomy, $i)
{
    global $post, $thepostid, $product_object;
    if (in_array($attribute_taxonomy->attribute_type, ['single'])) {

        $taxonomy = wc_attribute_taxonomy_name($attribute_taxonomy->attribute_name);

        $product_id = $thepostid;

        if (is_null($thepostid) && isset($_POST['post_id'])) {
            $product_id = absint($_POST['post_id']);
        }

        $args = array(
            'orderby'    => 'name',
            'hide_empty' => 0,
        );

        ?>
        <select
            multiple="multiple"
            data-placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e('Select terms', 'woo-variation-swatches'); ?>"
            class="multiselect attribute_values wc-enhanced-select"
            name="attribute_values[<?php echo $i; ?>][]"
        >
            <?php
            $all_terms = get_terms($taxonomy, apply_filters('woocommerce_product_attribute_terms', $args));
            if ($all_terms) :
                foreach ($all_terms as $term) :
                    echo '<option value="' . esc_attr($term->term_id) . '" ' . selected(has_term(absint($term->term_id), $taxonomy, $product_id), true, false) . '>' . esc_attr(apply_filters('woocommerce_product_attribute_term_name', $term->name, $term)) . '</option>';
                endforeach;
            endif;
            ?>
        </select>
        <button
            class="button plus select_all_attributes"><?php esc_html_e('Select all', 'woo-variation-swatches'); ?></button>
        <button
            class="button minus select_no_attributes"><?php esc_html_e('Select none', 'woo-variation-swatches'); ?></button>

        <button
            class="button fr plus add_new_attribute"><?php esc_html_e('Add new', 'woo-variation-swatches'); ?></button>
        <?php
    }
}
```